Flutter Scrollbar Doesn't Scroll to the Bottom Completely in ListView
I’m using a ListView.builder inside a Container with a fixed height in Flutter. However, the scrollbar doesn't scroll all the way to the bottom of the list. Instead, there is an extra space below the last item, and the scrollbar stops prematurely (see screenshot below).
https://imgur.com/a/JcgITuk
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
class MyListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 200.0,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Scrollbar(
              controller: _scrollController,
              thumbVisibility: true,
              trackVisibility: true,
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: 30,
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Text("List Item ${index + 1}");
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



I am getting at the end on windows;   btw can you wrap with SafeArea or move the widget to the center to check

this Works for me just fine
class MyListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
         height: 500,
          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          child: Scrollbar(
            controller: _scrollController,
            thumbVisibility: true,
            trackVisibility: true,
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount: 75,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Text("List Item ${index + 1}");
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


because you listview under the notification bar. you make below the notification bar.
you can fix that use SafeArea.
